# Specifying XY extent when rasterizing using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, xy, rasterization

I'm making some maps for landscape genetics in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 - raster maps of various variables (habitat type, river network, road network etc). I'm having trouble rasterizing a polyline road network to the specific size I want. The vector rasterizes fine but due to the extent of the road network being smaller than other data types (habitat, river network etc) that I have the resulting raster file has different min-max XY coords. I need all of the maps to be exactly the same size (and clipping to the road network raster would mean loosing data in other layers). I'm currently using the polyline to raster tool in the arc toolbox>conversion tools>polyline to raster.

Does anyone know if there is another tool in ArcGIS Desktop that I could use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ArcGIS, in every tool windows, you can go to Environments and set a custom extent (or based in another layer):

[image]

[image]

Also, you can set options by Default in `Geoprocessing / Environments`